# what can this ejs be look like in jade?

Tags: node.js, pug, ejs

I am learning how to build simple CRUD web application and instruction is written in ejs. However, I just start learning jade and do not know how can I convert this ejs code to jade.

```
<% layout( 'layout' ) -%>

<h1 id="page-title"><%= title %></h1>

<div id="list">
  <form action="/create" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div class="item-new">
      <input class="input" type="text" name="content" />
    </div>
  </form>

<% todos.forEach( function ( todo ){ %>
  <div class="item">
    <a class="update-link" href="/edit/<%= todo._id %>" title="Update this todo item"><%= todo.content %></a>
    <a class="del-btn" href="/destroy/<%= todo._id %>" title="Delete this todo item">Delete</a>
  </div>
<% }); %>
</div>
```

and this is what I've done,

```
extends layout

h1#page-title= title
#list
  form(action="/create" method="post" accept-charset='utf-8')
    .item-new
      input(type='text' name='content')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to know how to write that second part in jade. `Each` is one of Jades primary methods for iteration. And your code could be written something like this:

```
each todo in todos
  .item
    a(class="update-link" href="/edit/"+todo._id title="Update this todo item")= todo.content
    a(class="del-btn" href="/destroy/"+todo._id title="Delete this todo item") Delete
```

Here is a link for jades documentation about iterations: [Jade Iterations.](http://jade-lang.com/reference/iteration/)

Comment: I checked documents. I am more likely understand better with example. I was stuck in it, but I can go further now. I appreciate it